# Python SQL like query in Python dictionary, WHERE clause

Tags: python, dictionary

I am wondering if we can use where clause to query Python dictionary, an example as below:

```
myDict={"tradeId": (123,456,789,988,765,432),
"side":("B","S","B","S","S","S"),
"price": (100,123,111,222,333,444)}
```

I want to know the price of tradeId 432 which should return 444
I know we can do this is pandas data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, but a dict is entirely the wrong data structure.

This looks for `432` in the value of key `"tradeId"` and fetches the corresponding element of the value of key `"price"`:

```
>>> myDict["price"][myDict["tradeId"].index(432)]
444
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make SQL like queries out of the box.
But what you showed us can basically be written as a table.
Use pandas to transform it to a DataFrame then query the line.

*Note that you have one price more than tradeids and sides which makes the following not working. I removed the first price.

```
import pandas as pd

myDict={"tradeId": (123,456,789,988,765,432),
"side":("B","S","B","S","S","S"),
"price": (123,111,222,333,444,555)}

df = pd.DataFrame(myDict)

price = int(df[df["tradeId"] == 432]["price"])
```

price will be 555 and your dataframe df looks like this:

```
   price    side    tradeId
0   123     B   123
1   111     S   456
2   222     B   789
3   333     S   988
4   444     S   765
5   555     S   432
```